# Binary file writing performance Mono vs Core

Tags: c#, linux, mono, .net-core

I have a project where I need to be able to write small files (around 1kB) very fast (the faster the better) on a linux (centos) system. I have written a small console app that is writing a 1kB file from an array.

First I've tested it compiling the code under .Net 4.5 and then running it under mono. The 2nd test was the same code but moved to a net core project, that get compiled and run using dotnet command.

I was somehow expecting the same performance results (measured in files written/sec), but the tests showed that actually mono was much faster (35% in single thread, up to 60% in running on 3 parallel threads)

The method used to writing was FileStream.Write(byte[],offset,count).

Did anyone else encountered this situation? Is it normal? What would be the explanation for this?

Thank you!

```
var filepath = path + "File_M" + identifier + ".bbb";
var file = File.Create(filepath);
file.Write(fillChars, 0, fillChars.Length);
file.Flush();
file.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Also, did you compile in Release mode in both cases?

Comment: Hi Nate, I've updated with the piece of code that is doing the writing, fillChars is a static byte array populated once and used by all threads. The exe for mono was compiled for debug mode, and the core was just run with dotnet run command (not built as an independent app)

Comment: Can you show us all your code (including setup and measuring), so that we can easily test the same thing you are?